# Correct position of "of mine"

Tags: sentence-construction

The point of the question is that I want "of mine" to indicate "inattention".

Where should "***of mine***" be in the sentence below? This is the fault of the inattention of mine.

> This is the inattention's fault.

If I add "*of mine*" at the end of the sentence, then, Do I indicate "*the fault*" not "inattention" or what?

> This is the inattention's fault ***of mine***.

Comment: No English speaker would use this construction: Idiomatically, **this is the fault of my inattention.** Can you come up with a more likely example?

Comment: I can't quite get the intent - inattention is a fault or there was a fault caused by inattention. e.g. this thing happened because of inattention or I am inattentive which is a fault.

Comment: @cyborg Second one "there was a fault caused by inattention". In e.g. "this thing happened because of inattention"

Comment: Definitely wouldn't use "of mine" then, just "my". "My inattention caused the fault." It might be something you'd use if you were trying to be poetic, "This inattention of mine caused the fault."

Comment: @cyborg Can your last example be without "caused"?

Comment: It wouldn't sound right but would probably be understood.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use "of mine", then "The inattention of mine is at fault." Or, "This is the inattention of mine's fault."

However, it's probably more common to use "my" than "of mine". "This is my inattention's fault" would probably be the most common way to say this.

Comment: Why is mine's? Is it like "mine is"?

Comment: No. It indicates a possessive.

Comment: D M is "Mine" not Mine's possessive, cause I can't find it nowhere

Comment: @Boyep We are not really using "mine"'s possessive here. It's still the inattention's fault. The fault belongs to "the inattention of mine", not to "mine".

Comment: Using "mine's" doesn't make sense - "mine" is already an indication of possession. If you were talking about a coal mine then it would make sense to say "the mine's (mine is) closed," or "the mine's workers"  (workers of the mine) .